# dojo.mixin not working as expected

Tags: javascript, dojo

I think I am using dojo.mixin not as required...

I have the following code:

```
dojo.declare("A",null,{
    _configuration: {},
    constructor: function(configuration)
    {
        if(this._configuration.something === 2)
        {
            // we should never come here; the constructor is only called on a new instance which should still have an empty _somethingPrivate
            // because the class declaration says so
            console.log("why does this happen?");
        }

        // merge empty configuration 
        dojo.mixin(this._configuration, configuration);
    }
});

var myInstance = new A({ something: 2 });
var myInstance = new A({});
```

As far as I understand, you can use dojo.mixin to merge objects. I try to merge a default configuration object with given parameters (in an object), but the console output is "why does this happen?" so the parameters from previous object are merged into a *new* object.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

By the way: dojo version 1.6 (we cannot upgrade yet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you define the configuration as `_configuration: {},` it is shared across all instances of the widget.  So when you initialize the second instance, it sees the config from the first instance.  See http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dojo/declare.html for more details.

```
_defaultConfig: {},

_configuration: null,

constructor: function(config) {
    // clone to use a separate object.
    this._configuration = dojo.mixin(dojo.clone(this._defaultConfig), config);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!    As you say it, it sound like _configuration is a static member, but when I overwrite it (this._configuration = "somethingElse" in the constructor) it is only overwritten for the current instance ("this").    It is also something dojo.mixin does, which makes me wonder if this was intentionally done by the dojo dev team...

Comment: Since {} is an object, javascript will pass it by reference, while "somethingElse" will be passed by value. @Craig's solution is the best way I could find to pass around configurations.